# Layout responsiveness for mobile only in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning about react native layouts and according to my understanding, dp unit is not responsive on all devices. My layout is overflowing on smaller devices such as on 5 inch screens. How can I make sure my app is fully responsive on mobile only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use the the  [Dimensions API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions) to find the display size and then you can render different styles and ui placements for different display sizes. Define width and height with a percentage will work like charm than using dp units.